Media query is not working on angular application
In my angular application the css is working applying for media query(max-width: 800px).
Previously i have written media query for max-width 1440px and 1024px it is working fine but not working for 800px.
I am using styles.scss.
Angular CLI version 18
Any answer to solve this would be helpful.
Thanks in advance
here's my scss code for referece:
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .half-content{
    width: 85%;
    margin: 15px;
    h1{
      font-size: 22px !important;
      font-weight:bolder;
    }
    p{
      letter-spacing: 1px !important;
      font-size: 16px !important;
    }
  }
  .contact-description {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  .half:first-child {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60vh;
  }
  .half:last-child {
    height: 80vh; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .heading {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 30px !important;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .form-group label{
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    background-color: rgb(59, 198, 245); 
  }
  .half:first-child {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
    height: 40vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  .half:last-child {
    height: 60vh; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

Any way to solve that would be helpful.
